# Reading ALL attributes from a file (nested ones, too!)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

**TL;DR version: How to read attributes in an XML file that are children of an element which itself is a child?**

I have a XML file that contains data of various items.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<items>
  <item name="Item 1" value="10" weight="3.0">
    <mods healthMod="0" staminaMod="0" manaMod="0"></mods>
  </item>
  <item name="Item 2" value="20" weight="5.0">
    <mods healthMod="10" staminaMod="0" manaMod="0"></mods>
  </item>
</items>
```

So,as you can see, the item "base node" has attributes like value and weight. There is also a child element that contains attributes like healthMod, staminaMod and manaMod.

I have created a class that will hold the deserialized data:

```
[System.Serializable]
[XmlRoot("items")]
public class ItemDirectory {
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public Item[] items;


}
```

I can successfully read all elements and attributes from the item base nodes with this code:

```
Dictionary<string,Item> itemDictionary;

public static void FillItemDictionary() {

        itemDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Item>();

        item = new Item();

        string path = "C:/items.xml";


        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemDirectory));
        var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
        var deserializedItems = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream) as ItemDirectory;


        stream.Close();

        for(int i = 0; i < deserializedItems.items.Length; i++) {
            Item itemCur = deserializedItems.items[i];
            itemDictionary.Add (itemCur.name, itemCur);
            //Debug.Log("Item " + i + " name: " + itemCur.name + " Value: " + itemCur.value);
            //Debug.Log(itemDictionary["Item 1"].value);
        }

    }
```

Thereby, it read the items in the XML file and assigns them to a dictionary of items using the Item class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item {

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name = "";
    [XmlAttribute("type")]  
    public string type;
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public int value = 0;
    [XmlAttribute("weight")]
    public float weight = 0.0f;

    //mods
    [XmlAttribute("healthMod")]
    public int healthMod = 0;
    [XmlAttribute("staminaMod")]
    public int staminaMod = 0;
    [XmlAttribute("manaMod")]
    public int manaMod = 0;

}
```

**However, this does NOT appear to read and/or assign the nested attributes inside the "mods" element: healthMod, staminaMod, manaMod. How do I do this?**

The threads I found where either about PHP or used XMLElement.Load which I ahve even less experience with (none at all), but at this point I'm open to all suggestions because I spent the whole day searching for an answer! :)

Comment: Without making a class called `Mods` and have it be a property of `Item` I don't know if you can do this with the "easy way" of searization (Using attributes) if you want it like this I think you will need to have `Items` implement [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I suspected that I would have to create a sub class "Mods", and it's not a problem but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly;
I assume that the Item class would need a mods variable of type Mods. Ok so far. But how can I fill the variables inside this mods variable from the mods node attributes fromthe XML file?

Comment: exactly the same way you did `Item` in `ItemDirectory`.

Comment: Sorry I hit return and posted my comment above too quickly, I was editing it while you posted your own comment. Anyway, if I have the class Mods that contains the three variables (healthMod etc.), and the Item class has an instance of that class, how do I fill it? I guess I need to include the code into here?


`
    [System.Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("items")]
    public class ItemDirectory {
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public Item[] items;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should work

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item {

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name = "";
    [XmlAttribute("type")]  
    public string type;
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public int value = 0;
    [XmlAttribute("weight")]
    public float weight = 0.0f;

    [XmlElement("mods")]
    public Mods mods = new Mods();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Mods
{
    [XmlAttribute("healthMod")]
    public int healthMod = 0;
    [XmlAttribute("staminaMod")]
    public int staminaMod = 0;
    [XmlAttribute("manaMod")]
    public int manaMod = 0;}
}
```

One thing of note, you really should be using public properties instead of public fields to follow proper C# coding standards.

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestion. I have implemented it and it is in fact what another user on Unity Answers told me too, and it makes sense to me, but it still doesn't read the attributes from the XML file (or rather,the items that get read from the XML file) :(

Comment: Okay, I tested it again in a clean environment,so to speak, and it works now. Seems like I have a bug somewhere in my item database code. Thanks again for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Edit2: I think I know what I have done wrong. Before and during implementing your suggestion, I changed the mods in the XML file from attribute to element to test things, and forgot to change them back in all the confusion.